# Weird behavior calculating timezone difference

Tags: php

I can't explain this. I have the following:

```
     $time += $res['timezone']; (The array equates to -5*3600 (EST))
     return gmstrftime('%c',$time);
```

When I echo $res['timezone'], I get "-5*3600" which is correct. When I put the array value in front of the time variable, I get the incorrect time. If I comment out the array value and replace it with -5*3600, I get the correct result. Why??

Comment: What result do you get with the array variable there? Just saying it's wrong doesn't mean much if we don't know what is actually there, can you provide an example?

Comment: Can you add in what time you are getting? It would also be helpful if you echoed out the epoch timestamps you get from both methods.

Comment: Thanks for both ot your comments. I think I need to just work out the math for the different timezones and store that result instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the string "-5*3600" and the expression -5*3600 aren't the same thing. You could try to put `eval` around the array value, like so:

```
 $time += eval($res['timezone']); //(The array equates to -5*3600 (EST))
 return gmstrftime('%c',$time);
```

Note that this is a very bad idea, as it is both slow and insecure. If you want to store -5*3600 in the array, then calculate the value and store the result in the array:

```
$res['timezone'] = -5*3600;
```

Comment: Beat me too it!
(Just for kicks, do a var_dump on it's value look @ the results.)

Comment: I got it, thanks Marius. I will just store the difference in the database instead of the equasion.